# Spring boot with @async method with JPA entity update

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

I am having requirement where i have to create a Async task and Task will update some database entities.What are basic requirements to do that from transaction management perspective?

Issue is when i try to update any entity using JPA repository from @Async method ,it gives me exception as No thread-bound request found:In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.So i added @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) to @ Async method and now i am not getting exception...Is it right way?

Comment: Please try to work out a solution yourself. Then, if you get stuck, post the code in here and be as precise as possible. Unfortunately your question just says: "I have a general requirement, please do the research for me."

Comment: So the issue is when i try to update any entity using JPA repository from @Async method ,it gives me exception as No thread-bound request found:In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.So i added @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) to @ Async method and now i am not getting exception...Is it right way?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the detailed problem description along with code. Don't post it as comment ;)